# How to combine python list and create list within a list based on first element?

Tags: python, merge, nested-lists

I am trying to compile a python list based on first elements of nested list. But I am not sure what is the correct way to do that.

I have this nested list.

```
list1 = [[1, a, b, c], [2, b, c, d], [2, b, d, e], [1, c, a, d]]
```

I am trying to get an output like this.

```
output_list = [[1, [a, b, c], [c, a, d]], [2, [b, c, d], [b, d, e]]]
```

Comment: Take a look at this page: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) . A dictionary likely fits your need much better than a list like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accumulating with a defaultdict, and then using a list comprehension at the end:

```
>>> list1 = [[1, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [2, 'b', 'c', 'd'], [2, 'b', 'd', 'e'], [1, 'c', 'a', 'd']]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for first, *rest in list1:
...     d[first].append(rest)
... 
>>> [[first, *rest] for first, rest in d.items()]
[[1, ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'a', 'd']], [2, ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'd', 'e']]]
```

Comment: This is genius. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [[1, "a", 'b', 'c'], [2, 'b', 'c', "d"], [2, 'b', 'd', 'e'], [1, 'c', 'a', 'd']]
firstList = []
output_list = []
for i, list in enumerate(list1):
    if list[0] not in firstList:
        firstList.append(list[0])
        anotherList = []
        for j in range(1, len(list)):
            anotherList.append(list[j])
        bList = [list[0], anotherList]
        output_list.append(bList)
    else:
        place = firstList.index(list[0])
        anotherList = []
        for j in range(1, len(list)):
            anotherList.append(list[j])
        output_list[place].append(anotherList)
print(output_list)
>>>[[1, ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'a', 'd']], [2, ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'd', 'e']]]
```